# In WPF, is the FallbackValue used when the binding fails due to null references?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatrigger

My view-model exposes a list called `MyList` that may be empty or `null`. I have an element that I would like hide based on this state. If `MyList` is empty or `null`, then the element should be collapsed. If it has elements then it should be shown.

Here is my `DataTrigger`:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyList.Count, FallbackValue=0}" Value="0">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```

- What happens to this `DataTrigger` when `MyList` is `null`?
- Will it use the `FallbackValue` or will it fail?
- Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: There's some documentation here: [BindingBase.FallbackValue Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `FallbackValue` is used if the binding source path does not resolve, if the converter fails, or if the value is not valid for the property's type.

It will not be used if `null` is returned, unless `null` is not valid for the property type. In this case the `DataTrigger` will not be triggered. You can use `TargetNullValue` for this case.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyList.Count, FallbackValue=0, TargetNullValue=0}" Value="0">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```