# Runtime only data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, runtime

E2: My current solution is wrap the converter code in `try` block and return the dummy data instead.

In WPF you can specify that a binding should only occur at Design time. I am looking for an inverse of this functionality. But can't find anything. Does such a thing exist?

The reason for this behaviour is that I use a converter and it depends on values that are not initialized at design time.

I tried setting the `FallbackValue` property to something, but it is ignored.

So I end up with this:
[image]

Thanks

E1:
I have this line of code:

`<TextBlock Text="{Binding AccountID, Converter={StaticResource IDToNameConv}, FallbackValue=Test}"/>`

`AccountID` is a valid binding. I defined a converter above, that uses values that are not initilized at design time. Which causes `NullReferenceException` above. I'd like to see some dummy data that I provided in the `FalbackValue` property, but that does not work.

I'll try binding in code, but isn't there an easier way?

With just this:

`xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"`

and this:

`mc:Ignorable="d"` you have design time binding only. I would think that an inverse exists. But I didn't find anything.

Comment: This question is too broad, you need to narrow this down with some realistic example (with minimal code)

Comment: You can create the binding in code

Comment: According to this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33416567/in-wpf-is-the-fallbackvalue-used-when-the-binding-fails-due-to-null-references) the `FalbackValue` should work.. but does not, also added some code @TheGeneral

Answer (score 0):

Your IDToName converter should be modified so it can cope with whichever dependency it expects not being available.  You don't say what that is, so I can't be more specific.

When that isn't there then you could make the converter just return "Test".

Or you could make it return null.  I think then you could use TargetNullValue to return whatever default you prefer. This would be more obvious for any later maintenance than returning a text value from the converter.

Comment: I guess that `TargetNullValue` is as close as it can get... (It does in fact get triggered on `return null`) What is different in `FallbackValue` that it does not get triggered when the converter/binding fails?
E: The dependency is a `static` getter set in `App.xaml.cs`